# Proxmox, How to connect to remote VM

Tags: networking, ip, virtual-machine, remote-access, proxmox

I have Proxmox Installed with a static IP, I created a windows Virtual Machine, however when i type the Static IP offered by the hosting provider, I can't Connect to the Virtual Machine.

do i need to open a port? what are the directives?

Comment: which type of connection doesnt' work

Comment: it has been fixed already, thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in Proxmox the VM is set to have a network device under the Hardware tab in "Bridged mode". Then, go in to the Windows VM and check if the network device is showing up in the Device Manager (if not, first try changing the device model in Proxmox, and if that doesn't work you'll have to find drivers for one of the network devices). Then set the IP in the VM, following the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/). Confirm that your internet settings are working by opening up a command prompt and `ping google.com`.

Now you can run any server off of it and connect to it from the outside.